# Microsoft Word Grey Lines

Tags: microsoft-word

I copied 290 pages worth of information into Word from Wikepedia. I shortened it to 18 pages, changed some of the formatting and added in new pictures.

For the life of me I can not get rid of the grey lines. I have tried messing around with font, style and paragraph settings.

I think it is being caused by the header collapse / expand feature. But because of the many changes I made to the information I copied from Wikepedia, whatever purpose the grey lines originally held is now invalid.

[image]

Comment: Can they be selected?

Comment: No, I have tried highlighting it and then cutting / deleting it. But that did not work.

Comment: Have you try to copy the text in plain text editor like notepad, check these lines, edit, select again and copy back to Word?

Comment: I think I have now got rid of it. I think it was a table that only had a bottom border.

Comment: I had to just left click next to the line and then click no border.

Answer (score 0):

I have now got rid of it. I think it was a table that only had a bottom border. I had to just left click next to the line and then click no border.